# Cloud fusion to on-prem postgresql database connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to establish connection to on-premise postgresql database from cloud data fusion. But I' not able to resolve Host and port. Where can I find host and port for postgresql DB, also anything needs to be done for postgresql db to access from data fusion?

I downloaded postgresl JDBC from cloud data fusion hub. In Data fusion studio, I selected PostgeSQL a source. While filling details in properties, I'm not sure where to find host/port in postgresql.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is more "theoretical" than practical but I will try to resume it as easily as possible.

The first question you need to ask yourself is, is my PostgreSQL instance accessible via a public IP address ? If so, this is quite easy, all you need is an authorised user, the correct password, and the public IP adress of you instance (and the port you configured).

If your instance is not publically accessible, which is often the case, then the first thing to do is to setup a VPN connection between your on-prem database and the GCP Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) that is peered to your Data Fusion instance (if you setup a [private instance](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip) which you usually do for security reasons). Once this is done, Data Fusion should be able to connect directly to the PostgreSQL source via the exported VPN route / routes from you peered GCP VPC.

I am happy to edit my answer with more detail based on your follow up questions.